# MySQL - SELECT CONCAT AS ' ' & ORDER BY - Error/Not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is output (order_id, payment_type) together with a column title of 'Order & Payment Type Used' and (order_date, order_time) together with a column title of 'Date/Time'. Iv tried the below query in a number of different ways now but I always get errors.

**Query I am trying to execute**

```
SELECT CONCAT('order_id', ' ', 'payment_type') AS 'Order & Payment Type Used', 
       CONCAT('order_date', ' ', 'order_time') AS 'Date/Time' 
  FROM 'ORDER' 
       ORDER BY order_id;
```

**Error Result**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ORDER' ORDER BY
order_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Table . . .
**'ORDER'**

```
order_id
order_date
order_time
payment_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping of special names is with ` not with '

```
SELECT CONCAT(`order_id`, ' ', `payment_type`) AS `Order & Payment Type Used`,
  CONCAT(`order_date`, ' ', `order_time`) AS `Date/Time`
FROM `ORDER` ORDER BY order_id;
```

' is for strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use back ticks for column and table names,quotes are for strings and dates

```
`order_id`, ' ', `payment_type`
```

Comment: @2ndyearcompsciencestudent One more thing, back ticks are not necessary unless you use reserved names https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html That`s why on your ORDER table you NEED back ticks.In general avoid naming your tables or columns with reserved names.FROM `ORDER` ORDER BY sounds weird.

Answer (score 0):

If your column name contains any space or any special character then you must use back tick, other wise you can keep column name as it is or you can also use back tick but must not enclosed columns name under inverted commas as mysql treat it as constant value. You can use below query.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(order_id, ' ', payment_type) AS 'Order & Payment Type Used', 
CONCAT(order_date, ' ', order_time) AS 'Date/Time' 
FROM `ORDER` 
ORDER BY order_id;
```